# How to remove rows having a specific entry value from a data table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

To clearly state my question, consider the following table:

```
A   B   C  D 
12  3  -1  2
421 4  12  13
11  4  -1  55
4   36 44  18
```

I have a data set whose entries must be positive and I also have all of the missing value being labelled as -1. The missing values in my data set are only located in column C.

Question: How can I remove all the rows in this example table which contain the value -1 in R?

What I expect after this operation is to be left with rows 2 and 4 only.

Comment: Try `subset(df1, C >0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either

```
subset(df1, C >0)
```

as suggested or

```
dataset[dataset$C >0,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `filter` from `dplyr` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "A   B   C  D 
12  3  -1  2
421 4  12  13
11  4  -1  55
4   36 44  18", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
filter(df, C > 0)
#>     A  B  C  D
#> 1 421  4 12 13
#> 2   4 36 44 18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>